# Calcuate the integral $\int_1^{-1}dx\int_x^{2x}e^{x+y}dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Calcuate the integral $\int_1^{-1}dx\int_x^{2x}e^{x+y}dy$

Here is my working out:

Split the integral into their respective derivate parts: -

$$\int_1^{-1}e^xdx\int_x^{2x}e^ydy$$

The RHS is given as :

$$e^x\left(e^{2x}-e^x\right)$$

Finally:

$$\int^{-1}_1e^{3x}dx-\int^{-1}_1e^2xdy$$

Which is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{3}\left(e^{-3}-e^3 \right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{2}-e^{-2} \right)$$

I know that $\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{2}-e^{-2} \right) = \sinh(2)$

However, in my solutons it says that: $\frac{1}{3}\left(e^{-3}-e^3 \right) = -\frac{2}{3}\sinh(3)$, although I cannot seem to figure out how this was achieved, any clarification on this will be very helpful!

Comment: $e^{-3}-e^3=-(e^3-e^{-3})$

Comment: @Wolfuryo That would make sense for $-\sinh(3)$ although  considering the fraction, where does this appear from$\frac{2}{3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\because\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
$$e^3-e^{-3}=2\sinh(3)$$

So
$$\Longrightarrow-\frac{e^3-e^{-3}}{3}
=(-2\sinh(3))\frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the terse explanation. Although, I was aware of what $sinh(x)$ was equivalent to, though I still fail to see how the fraction is factored out from this

Comment: @Stackcans what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Aha! Thank you for the edit, now it makes complete sense to me +1